# Округление чисел с помощью Math.ceil

Tags: java

Почему, когда округляешь `double` с помощью `Math.ceil` (округление до наибольшего целого числа), `1.5` дает число `2`, но если округлить `3/2` то выходит `1`?

Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

`3/2` - это целочисленное деление (`int/int`), результатом которого будет 1. Сответственно округление в данном случае не играет роли